# ArrayList of Arraylist a remove function affects all Arraylists

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I created an ArrayList of 80 Arraylists. Each ArrayList inside, has the values 1-9.

However, when I delete a value from one of the Arraylists its deleted in all of them.

```
ArrayList<List> available = new ArrayList<List>();
ArrayList<Integer> possibleValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();



    for(int j = 1; j<=9; j++){
        possibleValues.add(j);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<=80; i++){
        available.add(possibleValues);  
    }

     int b = (int) available.get(0).get(2);
     available.get(0).remove(0);
     String s = available.get(80).toString();
     System.out.println(" " + s);

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you've added the same `ArrayList` `possibleValues` to `available` 81 times.  So, the `available` list contains 81 references to the same `possibleValues` list.

Any changes made to the list are visible through any of those 81 references.

If you don't want the changes visible to all references, just one, then you need to make 81 copies of the list to add:

```
for (int i = 0; i<=80; i++){
    available.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(possibleValues));  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're adding the same `ArrayList` to every index of the outer `ArrayList` . Any change to this `ArrayList` will automatically result in a change in the other `ArrayList` .

Nest your loops to always create a new `ArrayList` or construct a new `ArrayList` from the already existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are adding the values to same ArrayList. You need to create new Arraylist for 0 to 80 iterations.

```
for(int j = 1; j<=9; j++){
        possibleValues.add(j);// one ArrayList with values.
}


for (int i = 0; i<=80; i++){
        available.add(possibleValues); //Here adding same Arraylist 80 times.  
}
```

Try this one

```
  ArrayList<List> available = new ArrayList<List>();
  ArrayList<Integer> possibleValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  for (int i = 0; i<=80; i++){
    possibleValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int j = 1; j<=9; j++){           
        possibleValues.add(j);
    } 
    available.add(possibleValues);  
  }
```

Comment: Please explain why this code is working instead simply providing, +1 though :)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same ArrayList 81 times. ArrayList is a reference type, so any change to it will affect all items. It should be:

available.add(new ArrayList(possibleValues));